In C# LINQ, can predicate merging & pushdown be enabled for Unions?
Here is a short example demonstrating the problem:
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

var n2 = numbers.Select(
    v =>
    {
        Debug.Log(v);
        // some long operation
        return v;
    }
);

var query1 = n2.Where(n => n == 2);
var query2 = n2.Where(n => n == 3);

var unionResult = query1.Union(query2).ToList();

foreach (var i in unionResult) Console.WriteLine(i);

Upon execution, the log will indicate that each element of numbers is visited twice, this is problematic, not only because visiting an element in this case can be an expensive operation, but also that numbers could be a stream, with each of its element available exactly once.
I think the underlying mechanism of LINQ can easily merge 2 predicates to yield an optimal execution, which is equivalent to:
var unionResult = n2.Where(n => (n == 2 || n == 3));

Is there a solution to enable this abstract rewriting capability natively? I'm open to advanced stream processing library like RX, but using them may not be possible depending on compilers and environments (e.g. RxUnity is very old and may not have every modern feature)

Are you looking for a Union implementation that will do what you want? If so... I mean, sure, we could write one. Or you could just write code that works the way you intended.

coming from an Apache Spark background, I only expected optimisation already integrated in one LINQ engine to be available everywhere

Ah... so you're just here to complain that some feature wasn't implemented. Noted.

@tribbloid Your proposed query behaves radically differently.  An optimization is a program that behaves the same and accomplishes it with fewer resources.  You want something that behaves not just differently, but radically differently.

This question is clearly not opinion-based. Voting to reopen. The question is two-fold, and even clearly marked by question marks. There is no complaining here. The question is about whether query optimization takes place in LINQ.

@MarkSeemann Can you read other people minds?  You happen to know, objectively, why everyone else writes code the way that they do?  For us mere mortals who can't read minds, guessing why someone else did what they did is only ever an opinion.  And as mentioned in my previous comment, the proposed change isn't an "optimization".  Also, asking multiple questions is also inappropriate.  It even has it's own dedicated close reason.  That said, when multiple closes reasons apply, it doesn't make sense to vote to reopen a question just because you believe another close reason also applies.

@Servy there are duplicated question? but you are right I need to change the tone in my questioning. This question was written in haste ... now it should look better

Why RxUnity is mentioned here? You need that for Unity?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv yeah it is primarily built for Unity 2022

What built? I do not understand your comment and what you are trying to achieve.


I think the underlying mechanism of LINQ can easily merge 2 predicates to yield an optimal execution, which is equivalent to:

No, it is actually can't for example because the passed function can't be proven to be a pure one in general case (for example you already have a side-effect with Debug.Log). For example imagine the following:
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

var n2 = numbers.Select(v => 
{
     var res = Random.Shared.Next(v); // here can be any function, for example mutating shared state
     Debug.Log(res); 
     return res;
});

which should generate quite different results for var unionResult = query1.Union(query2).ToList(); and n2.Where(n => (n == 2 || n == 3)).

very good point, but is it possible to give it a proof of purity? It's not easy, but Apache Spark LINQ implemented it

@tribbloid C#'s LINQ was not designed for such things. In theory you can do something with IQueriable, custom LINQ provider and PureAttribute but in general arguably it is not worth the hustle.

:-< Fine, how about the more functional F#? In streaming query this should be a fairly important optimisation

@tribbloid. Not sure what you expect from streaming but take a look at Reaqtive.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks a lot for introducing! I'll start with RxSharp as RxUnity is very obsolete. Will update my question shortly
